# django model.objects.values() return related id instead of title

Tags: python, django

I want to get **Chapter model** data as json , i used **values() method** and it works but it return book id  not the book title and **i want the book title**

models.py

```
class Books(models.Model):
    title =  models.CharField(max_length=200 , unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    data_id =  models.IntegerField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return  str(self.title)




class Chapter(models.Model):
    book_id = models.ForeignKey(Books,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    chapter = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    date =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return  str(self.chapter)+" "+str(self.book_id)
```

views.py

```
class BookChapters(LoginRequiredMixin,View):
    def get(self,request):
        chapters =  Chapter.objects.values()
        return JsonResponse(list(chapters),safe=False)
```

json ouput

```
[
{
id: 1,
book_id: 237,
source: "nobel",
chapter: "18",
date: "2022-06-26T17:50:26Z"
},
{
id: 2,
book_id: 237,
source: "noble",
chapter: "19",
date: "2022-06-26T17:50:28Z"
}]
```

Comment: You are doing a very simple api. You are not using the full power of drf. Therefore, add a serializer and a viewset.

Comment: @EliasPrado  i do not want to use drf bcs i since there is only one view required that

Comment: @EliasPrado  if there is away to overwrite value() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'FK__COL' in the values():

```
chapters = Chapter.objects.values('id', 'book_id__title', 'source', 'chapter', 'date')
return JsonResponse(list(chapters), safe=False)
```

Doc reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values

Comment: it's works just as i wanted thank you